# DELIMITER error in MySql

Tags: mysql, ant, delimiter

I am using the following sql:

```
DELIMITER $$

DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `get_auto_increment_settings`$$

CREATE PROCEDURE `get_auto_increment_settings`()
BEGIN   
    select @@global.auto_increment_offset as 'offset', @@global.auto_increment_increment as 'increment' ;

END $$
DELIMITER ;
```

I stored this in db_auto_increment_settings_procedure.sql and when I am trying to execute this from ant, I am facing the following error:

```
[sql] Executing resource: /mysql/install/db_auto_increment_settings_procedure.sql
[sql] Failed to execute:  DELIMITER
[sql] com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'DELIMITER' at line 1
[sql] Failed to execute:  DELIMITER ;
[sql] com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'DELIMITER' at line 1
```

Comment: Your script is valid SQL - this issue is going to be something to do with whatever you're using to interpret it, I would guess because `$` is a special character somehow.

Comment: I tried using "//" and the issue is repeating.

Comment: What are you using to interpret the SQL? Isn't "//" commonly used as a marker for comments?

Comment: A little hint: `DELIMITER` is not a regular SQL statement. It's a command provided by MySQL clients (such as the command line client bundled with MySQL). If the DB library does not implement it, you need to parse the file into individual statements. No idea about how to do that in Ant.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The delimiter is used only by mysql client (not on API, driver ... etc).
So, it won't work.

See your error message :-

```
[sql] Executing resource: /mysql/install/db_auto_increment_settings_procedure.sql  
[sql] Failed to execute:  DELIMITER
```

Pretty sure this will work in linux system

```
mysql -u root -pxxx -h yyy < YOUR_SQL.sql
```

If applicable, you just manually create the stored procedure using mysql client,
and is a no-sweat solution.

If you need to create this dynamically,
this doc might provide some insight information
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/connector-j-usagenotes-basic.html

Comment: I used exec of mysql: <exec executable="mysql" input="path/file.sql"><arg value="database" /><arg value="-uUser" />
<arg value="-pPassword" /></exec> It works now. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Your procedure has one command, so delimiters are not needed -

```
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `get_auto_increment_settings`;

CREATE PROCEDURE `get_auto_increment_settings`()
SELECT @@global.auto_increment_offset AS 'offset', @@global.auto_increment_increment AS 'increment';
```